# How to create a public URL for my profile at careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

I have tried to create my profile on careers.stackoverflow.com yesterday. I observed that on the right-hand side, there's an option to make my profile public. I clicked on the button that says  'make profile public'. After that what I had was the below image.

[image: How to create a public URL?]

I have tried typing into the text box expecting that some script might get invoked to check what I am typing and give me a save button if everything was right. But no success.

Comment: I always thought you just type in some kind of name and it would be automatically saved once you do something else on the page... Then you can navigate to your profile by just following the link.  e.g., I have it set as `jeffmercado` so the link I get is [http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jeffmercado](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jeffmercado).

Comment: Well, even I thought the same. But it didn't work out for me. Is this a bug then? If so, how to notify to stackoverflow about it?

Comment: Well, just like this. The Careers folk have already been notified...

Comment: @Goje87:You are currently notifying the same. Have you checked by refreshing Javascript again(ctrl+F5)?

Comment: Is this broken AGAIN/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is broken right now.  We're doing some network maintenance right now and I'll have a fix deployed shortly thereafter.

Edit: FIXED!

Answer (score 4):

For a quick and dirty work-around, I found that if you use Chrome's developer tools (or any other live page editor) you can navigate and find that the form for that part of the page which has an ID of "public-route-form"

First, fill out the URL and check (or not) the search engine indexing, then go to the javascript console and enter:

```
document.getElementById('public-route-form').submit();
```

You should then see the JSON response:

```
{"Success":true,"Message":"saved!","Summary":"\r\n        Your profile is \u003cstrong\u003ecurrently public\u003c/strong\u003e at \u003ca class=\"route-link\" href=\"/<YOUR_URL>\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e/<YOUR_URL>\u003c/a\u003e\r\n    "}
```

That should at least get your public URL up until the bug gets fixed. It worked for me anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You should enter a unique name. After it public option become able to click.
When You enter occupied name You will get (picture one).
If name is available system save it automatically and after this action You can make profile public (picture two).

[image][image: When You anter occupied name You will get:]